# Listening to Recorded Music *Privately* During the 3 Weeks

Tags: halacha, sefirat-ha-omer, music, three-weeks

Do any of the poskim who rule that recorded music is assur during Sefirah/3 weeks distinguish between listening to recorded music in a **public setting** and listening to recorded music by oneself **in private**?

Comment: Related: http://judaism.stackexchange.com/q/29591/5

Comment: What would be the reason that there should be a difference?

Comment: Because when its played in public its related to "rikkudim u'mecholos" but when in private it may not necessarily be considered an act of simcha.

Comment: I've heard this before. I think someone definitely made a posek along those lines.