# Are there any halakhic issues with watching television or youtube videos during sefiras haomer?

Tags: halacha, sefirat-ha-omer

I am aware that the minhag is often to abstain from going to the cinema, but does this have any halakhic basis. If so, does the prohibition extend to other video forms

Comment: Note that not everyone holds that there's a problem with movies during Sefira.

Comment: Dupe? https://judaism.stackexchange.com/questions/29591/movies-and-music-during-the-3-weeks-according-to-rav-soloveitchik

Comment: @DonielF note that some have problems with going to the movies year round ;)

Comment: Maybe Bitul Torah and waisting time? Oh, not special to Omer though.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Movies and music during the 3 weeks according to Rav Soloveitchik](https://judaism.stackexchange.com/questions/29591/movies-and-music-during-the-3-weeks-according-to-rav-soloveitchik)

Comment: AFAIK, this is a "split problem". There is a common minhag to avoid listening to music during Sefira. Different opinions abound as to what "type" of music is allowed, but, many youtube videos are music videos, so that would tend to be prohibited. Non-music videos are OK (barring *tzniut* and language. etc. problems, of course.) Same concept would apply to TV. (But, seriously ... you still use a TV set??? Everything is streamed, now.)

Comment: @AlBerko Give the newbie OP a break. Perhaps he wants to watch a yeshivish D'var Torah on youtube?

Comment: We (usually) don't aggravate the rulings of our Sages - so if they (actually some) banned music on Omer we don't add everything else to it, like fitness or sports, movies, youtube, internet, fbook, insta etc. If entertaining music is forbidden - that's it. That's a common mistake of all newbies in a fitness class - "bring me twice the weight!" and boom, he collapses. So let's stick with what's ruled.

Answer (score -1):

According to this [dinonline.org](http://dinonline.org/2016/04/28/movies-during-the-omer/) article, there is no prohibition at all to attend the movie theater during the Omer even if there is background music as part of the movie. There are many people who are stringent, though and don't attend movies during the Omer, and numerous that never attend a movie theater at all. (I'm one of them, but it's not b/c of stringency. I just hate oily popcorn odors :-)

The dinonline article has a link to a more extensive PDF that explains the source of the music abstention minhag and explains the various lenient and stringent opinions.

In brief, though, if you follow dinonline's leniency, then it negates your assumption and, hence its extension. If you can watch movies in the cinema, then you can watch it privately, assuming that the video has just background music and is not a music video - based on the analogy. However, you should read the PDF, as it has a separate discussion about whether you may listen to non-live music.

Comment: Very interesting. Can you please summarize the argumentation between music and music theater?